# How do these multiplication relations of Conditional Probabilities work?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Could you please show how could I get from the left parts to the right parts for the following two relations? Thank you.

1) P(A|B)*P(B|C) = P(A,B|C)

2) P(A|B)*P(B,C|D) = P(A,B,C|D)

I would like to mention also the source where I found it:
https://youtu.be/lzN18y_z6HQ?t=253

Comment: Both are very suspect.  Have you tried some examples?

Comment: Are you assuming conditional independence?

Comment: I updated with the source where I found it.

Comment: In general, the proposed identities that you have written are false.  For a counterexample, consider the uniform distribution on $\{1,2,3,4\}$, consider $A=C=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{1,3\}$.  We would have $P(A\mid B)=P(B\mid C)=P(A,B\mid C)=\frac{1}{2}$.  I honestly didn't spend much time listening to the speaker in the linked video, but perhaps he has a valid use case where the identities work.

Comment: The closest identities I can think of would be Bayes' Theorem for multiple variables, you have things like $P(A,B\mid C) = P(A\mid B\color{red}{,C})P(B\mid C)$.